# How to check when Candy Crush level get cleared?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I was playing `Candy Crush` for quite a while and now nearing 500th level.

I would like to know the Date/time when I have cleared each level of `Candy Crush`. Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way on Android version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check because it is not tracked or it is tracked but not displayed.

I have checked the facebook version just in case and even on there it does not show the date where the level is completed.

It might not even be tracked by the app itself since you can adjust the clock on your phone to get more lives.